# How do you implement a cron job logic in web applications?

Tags: php, linux, web-services, cron

In our web application, we need to implement a business logic like: An order's status will be changed from "Submitted" to "Expired" after two weeks, if the seller does not take any action.

We are using php5+apache+mysql+linux. To implement this logic, we need something like a linux crontab task that is scheduled to run two weeks later when the order is submitted. The task is to trivially check whether there is action recorded in the database. If not, then update the status string in the database.

Is there some service like this in Apache or linux? What is an elegant way to implement this logic?

Thanks.

Comment: Cron is the defacto timer for Linux.

Comment: Since you're running on a LAMP enviroment the most elegant way would be to just make a cronjob :)

Comment: Create a cronjob set to run, say, once an hour. Create a list of tasks with due times and have your cron job read it and perform whatever tasks are due.

Comment: Since you already know you need to use cron, its not clear what you're asking.

Comment: So is it standard practice in web development to use cron? I was just wondering if there is any alternative to cron. Something purely PHP basd solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one Cron job, that will executes a php script ... 
This cron will run everyday in order to check and update status in database

Comment: Is there purely PHP basd solution?

Comment: @JunjiZhi no, you need to use cron. However, you could also start your script manually: visit the php script in your browser every day.